# Facebook article preview: "Curl error" or "Could not resolve hostname"

Tags: web-hosting, facebook, error

When I share my posts and articles from site to Facebook, it shows blank preview .  Meanwhile, when I post to Twitter, there's no problem.

[image]

Since it is showing a blank preview, I decided to go to Facebook Debugger and paste my link there. Here what it says.

[image]

UPDATE: Curl error is gone. However, this one shows on debugger

[image]

Answer (score 1):

if i understand your question correctly, you need to use

```
    <meta property="og:image" content="%%% />
    <meta property="og:title" content="%%%" />
    <meta property="og:description" content="%%%%" />
    <meta property="og:url" content="%%%%" />
etc
```

Its help to make good preview.